# Saving to an enum field in Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I am trying to make use of the enum feature that has been added to Rails. I had been waiting for this for quite some time.

Here is how I set it up:

**Product model:**

```
enum category: [:t_shirt, :hoodie, :jacket]
```

**Product controller:**

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)

  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :category, :price)
end
```

**New form**

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.select :category, Product.categories, include_blank: "Select a category" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This correctly populates the drop-down field in my form with the values of the different enum options which I have defined in the model.

However, when I submit the form having selected one of the categories from the drop-down, it gives me an error:

```
'0' is not a valid category
```

Even though my category field is an integer field and '0' is the correct integer associated with the category I selected in my form.

It also highlights the following line from the create method in my Product controller as the place where the error occured:

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

I am completely confused as to why this is happening. Would really appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: What values does `Product.categories` hold? also post your `server log` on form submit.

Comment: Your `enum` name is `category` or `categories`?

Comment: @Pavan this right `Product.categories` provide hash of `enum` values

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response everyone. Yes Зелёный's answer below is correct and solved the problem. Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead:

```
<%= f.select :category, Product.categories, include_blank: "Select a category" %>
```

Try:

```
<%= f.select :category, Product.categories.keys, include_blank: "Select a category" %>
```

Explain:

In `Product.categories` hash `{"t_shirt"=>0, "hoodie"=>1, "jacket"=>2}` but in `Product.categories.keys` array what you need `["t_shirt", "hoodie", "jacket"]` for `select` helper.